# How to type the symbol of vargha and delaney a effect size?

Tags: symbols

The vargha and delaney a effect size measure is always represented as:

[image]

I looked for a way to type this symbol in latex but couldn't find one. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Simply `\hat{A}_{12}` I'm not sure where the problem is.

Comment: `\hat{A}_{12}` ?

Comment: Thanks both. I never knew about `\hat`.

Answer (score 0):

The comments are perfect! But if a day you would to use two accents my suggestion is to adopt `accents` package.

Here a MWE with a screenshot.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}
$\hat{A}_{12}$, $\hat{\accentset{\circ}{A}}_{12}$, $\hat{\accentset{\diamond}{A}}_{12}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment:  (+1) from me!

Comment: @Electroelf LOL :-)